# How to save a webpage with Selenium IDE using CTRL + S?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to emulate the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the webpage as `html` but I can't make it work with Selenium IDE. I tried to look all over SO but there was nothing in particular about this.

I tried the following:

[image]

But when I ran the test, the popup did not show to ask me whether I want to save the page.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like **Autoit** to click in "Save" button that you can't reach with Selenium?

Comment: thanks for the proposed answer but I am looking for something directly implemented into Selenium since I can export the code into other languages and modify it !